# Angualr2- ngModel within ngFor not working. Model gets updated correctly but some error in the view

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel

I am working on a small task of creating a Trip Planner using Angular2. The work flow is as follows: The user will input **start point** and **destination** along with number of intermediate **stop points**. Once the user submit "Go" button, the Planner table appears, where user can input the intermediate stop points as well as add/remove the stop points. Somehow I am not getting the desired output as shown in the screen shot.[image: First Screen]

[image: 2nd Screen]

On adding new stop point, this is what I am getting...
[image: My output on adding a new stop point]

Desired output....
[image: Desired output]

**This is how the Tripdetails object looks like. See the difference between the object and the view.**

[image: console image]

The code are as follows:
**Trip.ts**

```
export class Trip {
    startPoint:string;
    destination:string;
    stops:number;
}
```

**TripDetails.ts**

```
export class TripDetail {
    startPoint:string;
    destination:string;
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Trip } from './Trip';
import { TripDetail } from './TripDetails';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent  { 
    trip: Trip = {
        startPoint : "",
        destination : "",
        stops : 0
    };
    tripDetails: TripDetail[];

    clicked(startPoint:string, destination:string, stops:string):void {
        let length = parseInt(stops);
            this.trip.startPoint = startPoint;
            this.trip.destination = destination;
            this.trip.stops = length;
            this.tripDetails = [];
        for (let i=0 ; i< length; i++) {
            let tripDetail :TripDetail={
                startPoint: "",
                destination: ""
            }
            if( i==0) {
                tripDetail.startPoint = this.trip.startPoint;
            }
            if( i== length-1) {
                tripDetail.destination = this.trip.destination;
            }
            this.tripDetails.push(tripDetail);
        }
    }

    syncData(index:number, locationType:string) {
        if(locationType == 'destinationLocation') {
            this.tripDetails[index + 1].startPoint = this.tripDetails[index].destination; 

        }
        else if (locationType == 'sourceLocation') {
            this.tripDetails[index - 1].destination = this.tripDetails[index].startPoint; 
        }
    }

    addStop(index:number):void {
        let stop:TripDetail={
            startPoint:"newStop",
            destination:"newStop"
        }
        this.tripDetails.splice(index,0,stop);
    }   

    removeStop(index:number):void{
        let destination = this.tripDetails[index].destination,
            arrlength = this.tripDetails.length;
        if(index==0){
            return;
        }
        else if( index== arrlength-1) {
            this.tripDetails[index-1].destination = this.tripDetails[index].destination;
            this.tripDetails.splice(index,1);
        }
        else{
            this.tripDetails.splice(index,1);
            this.tripDetails[index].destination= destination;   
        }
    }


}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container content">
    <div>
        <form>
            <label for="startPoint">From:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter start point" name="startPoint" [(ngModel)] = "trip.startPoint" >

            <label for="destination">To:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="destination" placeholder="Enter destiantion" id="destination" [(ngModel)]="trip.destination" >

            <label for="Stops">Stops:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter number of stops"  name="stops" id="stops" [(ngModel)]="trip.stops"  >

            <div class="go-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="clicked(trip.startPoint,trip.destination,trip.stops)">Go</button>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf = "trip.stops && trip.startPoint && trip.destination" class="trip-table  table-bordered">
                <table class="table table-stripped">
                    <thead class="thead">
                        <tr scope="row">
                        <th>FROM</th><th>TO</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tr *ngFor= " let stops of tripDetails; let i=index; let first = first; let last= last; trackBy: index ">
                        <td>

                            <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="locationFrom-{{i}}" [(ngModel)]= "stops.startPoint"  (input)="syncData(i, 'sourceLocation')" >
                        </td>
                        <td>

                            <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="locationTo-{{i}}" [(ngModel)]= "stops.destination"  (input)="syncData(i, 'destinationLocation')" >
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addStop(i)">+</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="removeStop(i)" >-</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>                
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule , FormsModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: It is working, but as you have `trackBy: index` expression.. it doesn't allow to element update.. Try removing `trackBy: index`, it should work

Comment: I tried this but still the issue persists. When I check in console, the values are correct but somehow in the View part, some issue.

Comment: Add a console.log line to the addStop function and see if it gets called twice?

Comment: It is called once. I have already checked that.

Comment: What's the problem? I can't see it on the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely correct with using `trackBy` to track the index, you just had some problems with that. `trackby` is needed when there is not an unique `ngModel` index to track (variable with property, e.g `[(ngModel)]="myItem.myProperty"`) and is therefore needed when dealing with primitive arrays, for example `trackBy` would be needed in below example:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <input [(ngModel)]="item" />
</div>
```

If you would try and modify the input fields above, the input field would instantly loose focus when typing something.

But you might say...

> My array is not of primitive type and my array `tripDetails` contains objects which can be tracked with the unique `ngModel` index?

True, in case you were **not** using a form, you would be fine without `trackBy`.

But since we are dealing with a form, Angular doesn't really care about the unique `ngModel`, but looks at the `name` attribute, which basically means that field suddenly doesn't have an unique `ngModel` with index to track.

So use `trackBy`

```
<tr *ngFor= "let stops of tripDetails; let i=index; trackBy:trackByFn">
```

and the corresponding function in the component:

```
trackByFn(index: number, stops: string) {
  return index;
}
```

Here's a

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/NrIfvjLv2nRhWynhJI3b?p=preview)